# How to identify web elements having same value?

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; width: auto; height: 435px;">
    <ul class="key-list member-list" data-section="all" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 435px;">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="TP2 - R1" data-id="2877523" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="TP2 - R1" data-session="{"session_id":"F_1_12_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="TP2 - R2" data-id="2877524" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="TP2 - R2" data-session="{"session_id":"F_2_12_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="TP2 - R3" data-id="2877525" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="TP2 - R3" data-session="{"session_id":"F_3_12_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="TP2 - R4" data-id="2877526" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="TP2 - R4" data-session="{"session_id":"F_4_12_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="TP2 - R5" data-id="2877527" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="TP2 - R5" data-session="{"session_id":"F_5_12_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="TP2 - R6" data-id="2877528" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="TP2 - R6" data-session="{"session_id":"F_6_12_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="Bottom Door" data-id="2877529" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="Bottom Door" data-session="{"session_id":"F_1_7_0","instance_id":124122}">
        <li class="row key-border single" data-name="Top Door" data-id="2877530" data-hidden="No" data-modified_timestamps="1498070218" data-desc="Top Door" data-session="{"session_id":"F_2_7_0","instance_id":124122}">
    </ul>
```

[image]

I have to write Xpath/CSS for the search icon but there are multiple search icons present on the page.

Comment: Screenshot Attc

Comment: data-name,data-id, data-hidden etc keeps on changing.

Comment: Do you want to select `li` controls?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to select controls with `li` tag which are having random values for data-name,data-id, data-hidden attributes. In this scenario, you can make use of predicates to select the required control, when there is no other suitable way to uniquely identify the control. For example, if you want to select the third occurrence of `li`, you can use following xpath:

```
//div[@class='slimScrollDiv']/ul/li[3]
```

Similarly, if you have to select the seventh occurrence of `li`, you can use following xpath:

```
//div[@class='slimScrollDiv']/ul/li[7]
```

Let me know, whether it works for you or I have misunderstood your question.